# SSL Configuration preventing browsers from making secure connection

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, digital-ocean, ubuntu-18.04, namecheap

I have a digitalocean One-Click Ubuntu Wordpress Droplet with a NameCheap domain.

I've never done anything with SSL before so I followed a tutorial (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-14-04). Once I made it to the end with no issues, I realized that it was a self-signed certificate and didn't remove the warning that browsers were giving and that I had to purchase one from a provider. Since my domain is through NameCheap, I went through them (Comodo?) and followed their linked tutorial for the setup (https://brettdewoody.com/how-to-setup-ssl-certs-with-digitalocean-and-comodo/).

I made it through that and browsers were bringing up an error saying that it was a self-signed certificate and it could be a problem. I went back through both tutorials and checked my stuff and tried to remove what I could of the original part. After blindly finagling things for a few hours, my site receives an A+ from this ssl checker (https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=vc2online.com) but browsers refuse to connect to the site (vc2online.com).

I don't even know where I need to start to get this to working properly.

Comment: Contact Comodo to have your purchase certificate reissued to include www.

Comment: That can definitely work, but Let's encrypt will solve it much faster, then you can contact comodo \ namecheap just for asking a refund.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently your issue is that you have 301 redirect from vc2online.com to www.vc2online.com but unfortunately your ssl certificate is only for vc2online.com, not www.vc2online.com.

You enabled HSTS so going backward won't be easy.

The quickest way to solve it is by using **let's encrypt** instead the comodo certificate. 
You can use [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntutrusty-apache) to fully automate the process. You will find out it is much easier (and cheaper) than comodo paid certificate

P.S. I think this question should be asked in super user / server fault.